# composing queries in Apollo Client

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

i'm learning to use apollo client and I saw that it used to contain "compose" method which combines multiple queries, so we can call two queries in a single request without explicitly write a whole new query.

lets say I have 2 queries

```
const getUsersQuery = gql`query getUsers ($name:String!){
  users{
    name
  }
}`

const getPokemonsQuery = gql`query getPokemon($id:ID!){
  pokemon (id:$id) {
    name
  }
}`
```

So a compose method will return an object which I can use to fetch these two queries in single request and include the variables for the two queries.

I didn't find a way to do it in the latest version.